# Problem about number of vertices of a graph

Tags: graph-theory

Here is a sample problem I need to know how to solve:

> The complementary graph $\overline{G}$ of a simple graph $G$ has the same vertices as $G$. Two vertices are adjacent in $\overline{G}$ if and only if they are not adjacent in $G$. If $G$ has 15 edges and $\overline{G}$ has 13 edges, how many vertices does $G$ have?

What I can explain myself is, that the sum of the degrees of all vertices of $G$ and $\overline{G}$ are 30 and 26 respectively. 
What I am not sure about is whether it follows from the above that the union of the two graphs is a complete graph with a sum of the degrees of its vertices equal to 56.

Could you help me out here, please?

Comment: Hint: The total number of possible edges is $\binom{V}{2}$ where $V$ is the number of vertices.

Comment: By definition, the union of $G$ and $\bar G$ is the complete graph in $n$ vertices, if $G$ has $n$ vertices.

Comment: @Jim Conant and @lhf: Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose $G$ is a graph of order $n$. Since $G$ is simple, you have $|E(G)|+|E(\overline{G})|=|E(K_n)|$, that is, $|E(K_n)|=28$. This amounts to solving $\binom{n}{2}=28$, and trying the first few integers shows $n=8$.

Comment: Thanks very much for the explanation!